# javascript setTimeout() not adding delay

Tags: javascript

Following is my code. Now when mouse is out I want to wait for 2000 milliseconds to resume my slideshow. But the Image changes as soon as mouse is out.
Can anyone help??

```
<img src="images/achiever.png" name="slide" alt="badge" 
width="130" height="130" onmouseover="pause()" 
onmouseout="javascript:setTimeout(resume(), 2000)" />
```

Comment: Maybe post the pause() and resume() functions here as well?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're *calling* `resume` and passing its return value into `setTimeout`, rather than passing `resume` into it. The `setTimeout` should look like this:

```
setTimeout(resume, 2000)
```

Just like `foo(bar())` executes *bar* and passes its return value into `foo`, `setTimeout(resume(), 2000)` *executes* `resume` and passes its return value into `setTimeout`.

---

Separately, note that you don't use the `javascript:` pseudo-protocol with any `onXYZ` attributes, only in places where a URL is expected (such as `href` on anchors). So your `onmouseout` attribute should look like this:

```
onmouseout="setTimeout(resume, 2000)"
```

The code in `onXYZ` attributes is always code, not a URL. The `javascript:` there actually ends up being a pointless [label](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.12).

Answer (score 1):

The argument to setTimeOut should be a function, and the correct way to pass a function as an argument is to use the function name without the parenthesis. If you add the parenthesis, you are actually executing the function and passing the result to setTimeOut. 
Hence, it should be `setTimeOut(resume,2000)`

Answer (score 1):

Please remove parentheses. Example : setTimeout(resume, 2000);

Answer (score 1):

The parenthesis around resume() are causing the function to be evaluated immediately.  Removing those effectively makes the function call a 'pointer' of sorts.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function pause() {
    //pause here
}

function resume() {
    alert('resumed');
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="images/achiever.png" name="slide" alt="badge" width="130" height="130"     onmouseover="pause()" onmouseout="javascript:setTimeout(resume, 2000)" />
</body>
```